# Predicting numbers using sklearn digits dataset - error

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, digits

I want to build a simple digit prediction model.

Therefore I:

1. load in the sklearn dataset
2. Use the DecisionTreeClassifier()
3. Fit to the data
4. Predict the new image

> ```
> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
> from sklearn import datasets 
> from sklearn import tree
> digits = datasets.load_digits() 
> clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
> clf = clf.fit(digits.data, digits.target) 
> clf.predict(digits.data[-1])
> ```

What did I do wrong?

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-b58a2a08d39b> in <module>()
----> 1 clf.predict(digits.data[-1])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem was that you were passing 1D array when the model requested a 2D array.

This should do the trick.

```
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn import tree
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold

# load the digits dataset
digits = datasets.load_digits()

# separate features and labels
X_digits = digits.data
y_digits = digits.target

# split data into training and testing sets
k_fold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=42)
for train_index, test_index in k_fold.split(X_digits, y_digits):
        train_features, test_features = X_digits[train_index], X_digits[test_index]
        train_labels, test_labels = y_digits[train_index], y_digits[test_index]

# fit to model
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = clf.fit(train_features, train_labels)

# predict on the testing features
print(clf.predict(test_features))
```

Also, have a look at [this](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.load_digits.html). It might provide you with further information.

Comment: Thank you. Can't I do this without k_fold? I wanted to have as minimal line of code as possible. Efficiency is not the issue here. I wanted to teach kids as minimal line as possible in the beginning.

Comment: @RakibulHassan Yes of course. The purpose of k_fold is to simply use all of the data for training with the scope of minimising over-fitting of the data. Instead of k_fold you can keep your original code and instead predict on `digits.data[-1].reshape(1,-1)`

Answer (score 1):

Since this seems to be your beginning of using sklearn, I would like to give you a basic idea of how the things are working in terms of features and samples.

To train a model you need to fit the classifier by using two attributes, i.e the feature vectors and a label for each vector. The feature vectors are represented by a `2D N*M` array where each row corresponds to a new sample and each column corresponds to a particular feature. The labels must be a `1D` array of size N, i.e. one label for each sample. (You can even have multiple labels for each sample but let us focus on one per sample for now)

Now using the above concept you can figure out what is the mistake in your predict function.

The `digits.data` is a `2D` array and digits where each row corresponds to a sample. Now `digits.data[-1]` is a `1D` array it does not have any columns in it, but you know that each individual number in this `1D` array is actually a feature (i.e. a column). Hence you need to reshape this `1D` array into a `2D` array of 1 row and N columns. Here numpy's reshape method can come handy. Just do `digits.data[-1].reshape(1,-1)` to achieve the desired effect and apply on predict method. Your code will then become

```
clf.predict(digits.data[-1].reshape(1,-1))
```

Consider going through the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) of numpy.reshape for more details of what and how the `.reshape()` method is doing.

Answer (score 1):

This should be your error:

ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[ 0.  0. 10. 14.  8.  1.  0.  0.  0.  2. 16. 14.  6.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.
 15. 15.  8. 15.  0.  0.  0.  0.  5. 16. 16. 10.  0.  0.  0.  0. 12. 15.
 15. 12.  0.  0.  0.  4. 16.  6.  4. 16.  6.  0.  0.  8. 16. 10.  8. 16.
  8.  0.  0.  1.  8. 12. 14. 12.  1.  0.].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.

You eliminated all but the last row. Is this what you wanted to do?

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([[11,52], [46, 49], [35, 26]])
arr[-1]
```

You could go with

```
digits.data[-1].reshape(-1, 1)
```

BUT only if you train you model only with a one dimensional array like the error says.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for the answers. All of you have responded to the point. Now, I understood the error. I actually took the example from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KTeVOb8gaD4&t=1213s and https://pythonprogramming.net/support-vector-machine-svm-example-tutorial-scikit-learn-python/

It was mostly the python version, in previous version of python predict function accepts 1D array but now it is deprecated so by surrounding the 1D array with braces like [1D array] will make it a 2D array. Now the following code is working perfectly.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn import datasets

from sklearn import tree

digits = datasets.load_digits()

clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()

clf = clf.fit(digits.data[:-1], digits.target[:-1])

clf.predict(digits.data[[-1]])
```

The output is array([8]).

Thank you once again for the help.